# How to plot a straight line from the beginning until the end of a chart in Highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

I would like to add a straight line from the beginning until the end of the chart in a fixed position with the chart itself (not the created HTML DOM).

I don't want to create a line using the renderer function, it's like a line chart type. It must represent a average value of all plotted values.

Thanks,
Eugenio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A plotline will do this for you:

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.plotLines

Or, you could create an additional line type series.

Either way, you will have to calculate the average value yourself.

Comment: Is it possible to add tooltip for the value as in the series?

Comment: If you do it as a regular line series, then yes.  If you use a plot line, no, but you can use a plotLine label...